PAD ExcelData (DataTable) Match
I'm working on a Flow and am getting stuck on the next action I'm wanting to take. Essentially, the flow in PAD (Power Automate Desktop) goes to a specific folder and looks for a file. From there, it moves the file to a destination folder. From their it launches an Excel instance and opens the file in the folder specified. After a few manipulations of data and different variables, the flow does a read from excel worksheet from the excel instance and stores it as ExcelData. From there (ExcelData) I used the find or replace in data table to look for items within the ExcelData for a specific text (In this case text is FP3000) from a specific column and stores the matched cells as DataTableMatches. Ideally, the next thing I'm looking to do is do a match action of FP3000 with items listed in the "Fleet Deal Drop Ship Dealer" (In this ex Matching FP3000 32557, 01954, 39943, 66284). Ideally, I'd like to set the match to occur when FP3000 is there and the Column prefix #s start with 32, 01, 39, 66, etc.  Unfortunately, after looking at a variety of ways I have not been successful and wanted to see if anyone has come across this and how they solved it.
ExcelData
I've tried DataTableMatches, but that converted things to numbers when it saw the matches, so then another conversion of # to text would need to be done.
